# Relation between $p$-Sylow subgroups of a group $G$ and the $p$-Sylow subgroups of $G/H$

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory, quotient-group

I'm learning about the Sylow theorem and the p-Sylow subgroups. In certain applications of the Sylow Theorem one considers the $p$-Sylow subgroups of the quotient group $G/H$ to conclude a statement about a $p$-Sylow subgroup in the group $G$.

What is the general relation between them?

If $G$ is a group such that ${\rm card}(G) = p^s \cdot m$ and such that $\gcd(p,m) = 1$. I think that if $P$ is a unique $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G/H$ with order $p^s$ then there will be a unique $P'$ such that $P'$ is a $p$-Sylowsubgroup but in $G$ with the same order. Is that true and/or are there any other known relations?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is $H$? $\space$

Comment: @D_S I think it would be better to have $H$ as a normal subgroup. Would there be any relations if $H$ is not a normal subgroup? Since then $G/H$ would not be a group.

Comment: This also depends on how co-prime to $p$ the index is.

Comment: @Randall Can you give me an example?

Comment: Let $G=S_3$, $H$ be the cyclic subgroup of order $3$, and $p=2$. Then $G/H$ has a unique Sylow $2$-subgroup of order $2$, but $G$ has three Sylow $2$-subgroups, all of order $2$.

Comment: @Randall: If the order of $G/H$ is divisible by $p^s$, and that's also the highest power of $p$ that divides $|G|$, then the index is "not at all coprime" to $p$: it is a multiple of $p^s$.

Comment: A relation is that the homomorphic image of any Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of $G$ under the natural projection $\pi:G\to G/H$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup $\overline{P}$ of $G/H$. Arturo's example shows that we may have $\overline{P}=\overline{P'}$ for distinct $P,P'$. Here $\overline{P}\simeq P/(P\cap H)$.